# Segmentation Fault in aerospike_key_get()

Tags: aerospike

I'm using the C client library of Aerospike. The given code is giving me a lot of trouble:

```
RtCliErrors RtZonalDao::rtDispZonalCodes(char * p_ZnCodeListName, vector <struct RtDispRgZnCode> & dispRgZnCodeVec)
{
    printf("\n[%s::%d] === Inside rtDispZonalCodes() === \n",__FILE__,__LINE__);

    as_error l_asError;
    as_key l_key ;
    as_record l_rec;

    try{
            if(aerospike_cluster_is_connected(&RtDbConnection::ms_aerospikeIns) == true)
            {
                    printf("\n[%s::%d] === aerospike connection OK ===",__FILE__,__LINE__);
            }
            else{
                    printf("\n[%s::%d] aerospike is not connected",__FILE__,__LINE__);
                    return RT_FAILURE;
            }

            if(p_ZnCodeListName==NULL)
            {
                    printf("\n[%s::%d] Error: Null value of ZnCodeListName \n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
                    return RT_FAILURE;
            }

            if(p_ZnCodeListName!=NULL&&p_ZnCodeListName[0]==0)
            {
                    printf("\n[%s::%d] Error: Null value of ZnCodeListName \n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
                    return RT_FAILURE;
            }

            as_key_init_str(&l_key, "bar", "rg_zn_cd_list_id_name", p_ZnCodeListName);

            printf("\n[%s::%d] Key initialised successfully\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
            as_record* p_rec=&l_rec;

            if (aerospike_key_exists(&RtDbConnection::ms_aerospikeIns, &l_asError, NULL, &l_key, &p_rec) == AEROSPIKE_ERR_RECORD_NOT_FOUND)
            {
                    as_record_destroy(&l_rec);

                    as_key_destroy(&l_key);

                    printf("\n[ %s::%d ]--> Exception: , RG_ZN_CD_LIST not present in Db\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);

                    return RT_RG_ZN_CD_LST_NOT;
            }

            else
                    printf("\n[%s::%d] Primary Key found\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
            if (aerospike_key_get(&RtDbConnection::ms_aerospikeIns, &l_asError, NULL, &l_key, &p_rec) != AEROSPIKE_OK)
            {
                    as_record_destroy(&l_rec);

                    as_key_destroy(&l_key);

                    printf("\n[%s::%d] Exception! Error Code: %d, Error Msg: %s\n",__FILE__,__LINE__, l_asError.code, l_asError.message);

                    return RT_FAILURE;

            }


            printf("\n[%s::%d] Fetch success\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
            as_record_destroy(&l_rec);

            as_key_destroy(&l_key);


            return RT_SUCCESS;

    }//end of try
    catch(...)
    {
            printf("\n[%s::%d] Default Exeption Caught \n",__FILE__,__LINE__);

            as_record_destroy(&l_rec);

            as_key_destroy(&l_key);
            return RT_FAILURE;
    }
```

}

I’m at my wits’ end here. I’ve been trying to find out the problem in my client code but still unsuccessful. I’m getting weird observations. The above API runs fine the very first time it’s called , but when I call it for the second time it gives segmentation fault. Given below is a snippet of Valgrind output:

```
==14471== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14471==    at 0x4A0A965: memcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1023)
==14471==    by 0x4E77C4B: as_command_parse_bins (as_command.c:985)
==14471==    by 0x4E7805E: as_command_parse_result (as_command.c:1167)
==14471==    by 0x4E787D2: as_command_execute (as_command.c:492)
==14471==    by 0x4E6DF22: aerospike_key_get (aerospike_key.c:136)
==14471==    by 0x4042D0: RtZonalDao::rtDispZonalCodes(char*, std::vector<RtDispRgZnCode, std::allocator<RtDispRgZnCode> >&) (RtZonalDao.cpp:90)
==14471==    by 0x404679: RtZonalDao::rtAddRgZnCodeToList(RtRgZonalCodes*, char*) (RtZonalDao.cpp:370)
==14471==    by 0x407665: RtZonalDaoTest::rtAdd() (RtZonalDaoTest.cpp:94)
==14471==    by 0x403134: main (RtMain.cpp:194)
==14471==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14471==    at 0x4041A8: RtZonalDao::rtDispZonalCodes(char*, std::vector<RtDispRgZnCode, std::allocator<RtDispRgZnCode> >&) (RtZonalDao.cpp:24)
==14471==
==14471== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==14471==    at 0x4A0A9AB: memcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1023)
==14471==    by 0x4E77C4B: as_command_parse_bins (as_command.c:985)
==14471==    by 0x4E7805E: as_command_parse_result (as_command.c:1167)
==14471==    by 0x4E787D2: as_command_execute (as_command.c:492)
==14471==    by 0x4E6DF22: aerospike_key_get (aerospike_key.c:136)
==14471==    by 0x4042D0: RtZonalDao::rtDispZonalCodes(char*, std::vector<RtDispRgZnCode, std::allocator<RtDispRgZnCode> >&) (RtZonalDao.cpp:90)
==14471==    by 0x404679: RtZonalDao::rtAddRgZnCodeToList(RtRgZonalCodes*, char*) (RtZonalDao.cpp:370)
==14471==    by 0x407665: RtZonalDaoTest::rtAdd() (RtZonalDaoTest.cpp:94)
==14471==    by 0x403134: main (RtMain.cpp:194)
==14471==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==14471==    at 0x4041A8: RtZonalDao::rtDispZonalCodes(char*, std::vector<RtDispRgZnCode, std::allocator<RtDispRgZnCode> >&) (RtZonalDao.cpp:24)
==14471==
==14471== Invalid write of size 8
==14471==    at 0x4A0A9AB: memcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1023)
==14471==    by 0x4E77C4B: as_command_parse_bins (as_command.c:985)
==14471==    by 0x4E7805E: as_command_parse_result (as_command.c:1167)
==14471==    by 0x4E787D2: as_command_execute (as_command.c:492)
==14471==    by 0x4E6DF22: aerospike_key_get (aerospike_key.c:136)
==14471==    by 0x4042D0: RtZonalDao::rtDispZonalCodes(char*, std::vector<RtDispRgZnCode, std::allocator<RtDispRgZnCode> >&) (RtZonalDao.cpp:90)
==14471==    by 0x404679: RtZonalDao::rtAddRgZnCodeToList(RtRgZonalCodes*, char*) (RtZonalDao.cpp:370)
==14471==    by 0x407665: RtZonalDaoTest::rtAdd() (RtZonalDaoTest.cpp:94)
==14471==    by 0x403134: main (RtMain.cpp:194)
==14471==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==14471==
==14471==
==14471== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==14471==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==14471==    at 0x4A0A9AB: memcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:1023)
==14471==    by 0x4E77C4B: as_command_parse_bins (as_command.c:985)
==14471==    by 0x4E7805E: as_command_parse_result (as_command.c:1167)
==14471==    by 0x4E787D2: as_command_execute (as_command.c:492)
==14471==    by 0x4E6DF22: aerospike_key_get (aerospike_key.c:136)
==14471==    by 0x4042D0: RtZonalDao::rtDispZonalCodes(char*, std::vector<RtDispRgZnCode, std::allocator<RtDispRgZnCode> >&) 

    (RtZonalDao.cpp:90)
    ==14471==    by 0x404679: RtZonalDao::rtAddRgZnCodeToList(RtRgZonalCodes*, char*) (RtZonalDao.cpp:370)
    ==14471==    by 0x407665: RtZonalDaoTest::rtAdd() (RtZonalDaoTest.cpp:94)
    ==14471==    by 0x403134: main (RtMain.cpp:194)
    ==14471==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
    ==14471==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
    ==14471==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
    ==14471==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
    ==14471==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
    ==14471==
    ==14471== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==14471==     in use at exit: 248,960 bytes in 70 blocks
    ==14471==   total heap usage: 126 allocs, 56 frees, 260,256 bytes allocated

Is there any problem in any part of the code I’ve provided above?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the same question was asked on the [Aerospike forum](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/segmentation-fault-in-aerospike-key-get/5279) and answered there. I suggest either not crossposting on both channels or, if you do, providing cross links on both sides.